# If path contains directory

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a digital marketing tag on every page which falls under a particular URL path, say `example.com/sachin` under the `sachin` directory.

I've tried `if (location.href === 'example.com/sachin.*/')` but somehow the condition doesn't seem to work.

What will be the correct if condition for `location.href` if I want to cover all different resources with in the URL path say under sachin directory?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Henrik, I actually want to trigger digital marketing tag on every page which falls under a particular url path say http://example.com/sachin/ under sachin directory. I created a javascript code by using location.href like if (location.href === 'http://example.com/sachin/.*/') but somehow the condition doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to check if the URL contains example.com/sachin. It's highly rarely that any URL ever would contain 4 forward-slashes but what you would do is utilize indexOf.

```
if(location.href.indexOf("example.com/sachin/") != -1){
     //Do something
}
```

This basically says, if "example.com/sachin/" is found somewhere in the given string(in location.href in this case) on an indexposition that is not -1(which means that it doesn't exist), then execute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match needed resources.

Something like that:

```
if(location.href.match(/^http:\/\/example.com\/sachin\//)){
  //your staff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to check for a specific directory in a url.

```
function urlContains(url, value) {
  return ~url.indexOf(value);
}

if (urlContains(location.href, "/sachin/")) {
  // found

} else {
  // not found
}
```

The [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method checks a string for the value that is passed and returns -1 if a result was not found.

Instead of checking for `== -1` or `!= -1`  you can use the [Bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) operator `~` to convert -1 to 0, which is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, non-zero values are treated are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values in javascript.